# If statement not executing, but elseif and else are

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

So, I am scratching my head on this one. My original "IF" statement is not executing when true (I know it's true because I have echoed the variable and it's what should trigger the code). BUT, if the IF statement is not true, the elseif and else statements work fine. Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // have also tried only one "=" sign//
    if ($count==0){
        //This is not appearing//
        echo "Your search did not yield any results. Please try another search."; 
    } else if ( //other conditions// ) {
        //code that is working fine//
    } else {
        // more code that is working fine 
        // (happens to be the same as the original if statement)
    }
    echo $count; //is printing 0 correctly, but the if statement for $count=0 not happening//
    ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's impossible. If the condition in the if is true, the if will execute. Your echoing back of the variable must be inaccurate.

Comment: What does `var_dump($count);` give you?

Comment: I haven't used the MySQL libraries themselves for years but is the count it returns returned as an integer? I'm sure it will be but try $count===0 or $count=='0' if its a string

Comment: @ste http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php that seems to return an int, so I don't think that is the case.

Comment: Move your `echo $count` (and change it to `var_dump($count)`) to just before the if statement. It's hard to say without seeing all the code, but it's possible that you are reassigning `$count` at some point.

Comment: Are you modifying the count inside those other statements?  I know it seems really simple, but if count is being changed in the logic, that could be why it prints '0' at the very end.  Is it confirmed '0' before even going into the logic?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, had a guy at work look at it and he found the error. It was in something I didn't report because I didn't think it would have an effect. I had a while statement before the original if, but I didn't need it to execute unless the if was false. When I moved it to below the original if and changed elseif to another if bracketed within the while statement, it worked fine.

Comment: I hope you learned from this incident not to omit any code in your next question.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend switching to mysqli and not use the deprecated mysql series of commands.

But, in answer to your problem, you should check your SQL statement. mysql_num_rows returns a row count on success OR false on failure. The integer value of false is 0.